# Jquery Form Validation in ColorBox

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, colorbox

I click on a link which opens Colorbox ... in that Colorbox i have loaded a Form(addproject.php)

```
<a href="#" id="addproject">
<script>
          $('#addproject').on('click',function(){
              $.colorbox({
                          width:'450px',height:'370px',top:'80px', opacity:0.3, iframe:true,href:"addproject.php"});
                    });
       });
</script>
```

I want to validate all form fields of addproject.php which is displayed in Colorbox. The Code in addproject.php is --->

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#addpro").on("click",function(){

          $("#validate").validate({
            rules: {
                    pro_name: "required",
                    pro_desc: "required",
                   },
            messages: {
            pro_name: "Enter Project Name",
            pro_desc: "Enter Project Description",
            },           
           });               

            var pro_name=$("#pro_name").val();
            var pro_desc=$("#pro_desc").val();

$.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               url:"./addprojects.php",
               data:{
                   pro_name:pro_name,pro_desc:pro_desc
               },
               success:function(data){
                 $("#message").html(data);  
               },

            });

        });

    });
</script>

<form name="addproject" id="validate" action="" method="POST">
<td> Project Name<span style="color: red" ><sup>*</sup></span> :</td> <td> <input type = 'text' name = 'pro_name' id = 'pro_name'/> </td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>Project Description <span style="color: red;" ><sup>*</sup></span> :</td> <td> <input type = 'text' name = 'pro_desc' id= 'pro_desc'/> </td> </tr>
<td><input type = 'button' id="addpro" name = 'save' value='submit' /> </td> </tr><
```

The Ajax Call goes to a page where the form data is finally inserted(Insert Query is written in addprojects.php)

The Form Does not get Validated .. and the Jquery Library i Used are (on page addproject.php)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

where Am I going wrong to validate the form fields?

Comment: You haven't told us what the problem is, but... if you've posted the entire source of addproject.php, you aren't loading the jQuery library.

Comment: @JasonP --> My Problem is with Form Validations ,,,, it does not get Validated .. and i am using CDN for Jquery Library

Comment: the post is being made either fields are valid or not since the instructions are being called from `click` event, check your validation plugin to see if there's a `success` event or something and then make the `post` there